# Python PIL converts PNG image to black and white

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to combine a pair of Depth and RGB images with Python *PIL*:

[image: Depth Image]
[image: RGB Image]

Here's the simple code:

```
image1 = Image.open('1.png').resize((256, 256))
image2 = Image.open('2.jpg').resize((256, 256))
new_image = Image.new('RGB', (512, 256))

x_offset = 0
new_image.paste(image1, (x_offset, 0))
x_offset += image1.size[0]
new_image.paste(image2, (x_offset, 0))

new_image.save('3.jpg',image2.format)
```

But when using *PIL*, it automatically converts the depth image to a black and white version:

[image: Final Image]

How can I save the depth image as it is in its original form?

Comment: Your depth image is PNG colortype 6, meaning it is RGBA (4-channel including alpha) and your other image is 3 channel RGB. You are forcing a 3-channel output by using JPEG, but have done nothing specific to to tell PIL how you want it to handle the incompatbility so I suspect you have got its default decision - whatever that is! I don't know PIL but would suggest magbe trying to save as PNG, or converting the depth image to pure greyscale RGB where R=G=B. Sorry I can't tell you the answer just give you an idea what may be wrong.

Comment: What I am saying is that you need to be a bit careful about exactly what is in each channel of your depth image. Is the alpha channel the distance to the object? Or the distance in the R, or G or B channel? What is in the other channels?